# Alexa top dataset

Tags: web-crawling, traffic

Is Alexa's Top available in a dataset format?

Several datasets exist, but include only basic information, like domains and their positions in the top.

What about other info, like category of the website, search visits, visitors locations, etc. as presented here: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com ?

Answer (score 4):

I know that 1-2 years ago, Alexa had a free API for this on [data.alexa.com](http://data.alexa.com). Now it returns a 404 error.

There are a few software out there that promise data from Alexa but actually they scrap the website which is illegal.

The only way I know is via Amazon web servers but it is a paid service. 0.15$/1000 requests. You can see details here [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/awis/).

The price has changed to $0.0025 per URL.

Answer (score 4):

Alexa is a division of Amazon.  They still have an API, but you need to access it as a paid service through AWS:

Alexa Web Information Service
http://aws.amazon.com/awis/

and

Alexa Top Sites
http://aws.amazon.com/alexatopsites/